# How do I check two input[text] values against each other, using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quick question...How do I check two input[text] values against each other?

Here's what I have so far:

```
$('#BuyItNowPrice').blur(function(){

    if($(this).val() > $('#StartingPrice').val()){
        alert("Please make sure that your BuyItNow price is greater than your Starting Price!");
    }
});
```

I haven't really touched on form validation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Comment: That looks like it should work. Is it not? I know there can be some weirdness with when using blur(). It might be better to check it when the form submits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're comparing floats so use `parseFloat` if you're using integers use `parseInt`.

`parseFloat($(this).val()) > parseFloat($('#StartingPrice').val())`

Answer (score 1):

```
if(parseFloat($(this).val()) > parseFloat($('#StartingPrice').val())) 
{
```

Answer (score 0):

`if(parseInt($(this).val()) > parseInt($('#StartingPrice').val())){ ..`

use parseFloat() in case it alows decimals